# Get media content tags from RSS feeds

Tags: java, rss, rss-reader, rome

As weird as it seems when parsing entries from I cannot find an easy when to get `<media:content>` from RSS feed without parsing XML document with a library.

I cannot find media content either in enclosures or markups.

For example for feed https://www.forbes.com/energy/feed/. I have no enclosures or markups in `FeedEntryImpl`

Why that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using the Rome Java API to access metadata fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342619/using-the-rome-java-api-to-access-metadata-fields)

Comment: No It doesn't. I cannot find a proper way to get images ! Several examples are posted on SO but none of them work!

Answer (score 0):

You should only read it as content since the parser ignores media: and reads the tag only as < content >  but without the spaces, it works for all tags that have tag that has semicolon in it, it only reads the part of the tag after the semicolon